# Как передать параметры функции js?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть такая функция в плагине: onselect:  ...**clicker**,...

А вот ее описание:

```
var clicker = function(item) {
        //createInput(item._value);
    };
```

Первый параметр **item** функции **clicker** передается самим плагином, как передать в функцию свои параметры?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onselect:  function(e) {clicker(params);}`

?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте дополнительные аргументы.

```
var clicker = function(item, var1, var2, var3) {
            //createInput(item._value);
        };
```

Если Вы имеете ввиду onselect из html, то будет вызов будет следующим

```
<element onselect="clicker(здесь нужные Вам аргументы через запятую, например 'item', 'var1', 'var2', 'var3')">
```

Comment: Как записать эти параметры в месте вызова? чтобы было понятно - приведу полный код:

`$("#language").fcbkcomplete({
     json_url: "/other/GetLanguage",
     cache: true,
     filter_case: true,
     filter_hide: true,
     newel: false,
     maxitems: 10,
     filter_hide : true,
     complete_text: "Enter language",
        onselect:  clicker,
        onremove:  removeItem
 });`

Обратить внимание на: onselect:  clicker,

Comment: Можете преобразовать в ответ - это решение сработало. Благодарю Вас